# What will be the mathematical formula to fetch the position of a letter from this string?

Tags: encryption

[image]

The above full string is a combined form of two different strings named string-1 and string-2. Both strings has equal length of 32 characters. There is two other parameters **interval** and **size**. string-1 is broken into pieces of length = **interval** and string-2 is broken into pieces of length = **size** to form the full string. once all the pieces of string -2 is put in full string, pieces of string-1 is padded to the full string.

possible values for **size** variable are : 2, 4, 8, 16
possible values for **interval** variable are : any value from 1 to value of **size** variable

My requirement is to write a mathematical equation fetch index(in full string) of nth number of character of string-1 without separating the full string into its 2 original strings.

for e.g.
In above full string, if I want to fetch 5th character of string-1 it will be **'2'** whose index in full string is **12**.
and for 6th character which is **'1'** has the index **15**.

P.S. index of the character is counted from 0 to **index**, and the nth character is counted from 1 to **n**

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from somewhere else and sharing it here.

PHP Code :

```
min(32,(floor($n/$interval)*$size))+$n
```

Answer (score 0):

```
index = group_size*group_number + group_offset
  where
    group_size   = size + interval
    group_number = floor((character - 1)/interval)
    group_offset = (character - 1) % interval
```

Or

```
index = (size + interval)*floor((character - 1)/interval) + (character - 1) % interval
```

With your examples:

```
character = 5, interval = 1, size = 2
index = (2 + 1)*floor((5 - 1)/1) + (5 - 1) % 1
      = 3*floor(4) + 0
      = 12


character = 6, interval = 1, size = 2
index = (2 + 1)*floor((6 - 1)/1) + (6 - 1) % 1
      = 3*floor(5) + 0
      = 15
```